# Does Consul save the health check history of a service?

Tags: consul, hashicorp

I am using Hashicorp Consul for Health Check in our system. 

Does Consul have any API to get the health check History?

For example; let's say I have a service called A and this service was down for the past hour and now it's up, What I need is to get this info ( service was down in the past 1 hour ).

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

No, the history information is not available from consul server itself. You can see that their /health API, you have no way to get the health at specific point of time.

If you need that functionality, you will have to either record it periodically in an audit table, or log to something like Splunk, and pull the history accordingly.